# Where can I find the complete Tour de France routes?

Tags: racing, tour-de-france

I fear this may not be fully on topic as I'm looking for some map data.

I would like to get the routes for all the stages of Tour de France for a particular year, ideally on Google Maps/Earth. Here's what I've tried so far:

- [Le Tour](http://www.letour.com/le-tour/2016/us/overall-route.html) - Tour de Fance Official website
- [Tour de France Manche](http://www.tourdefrance-manche.co.uk/) - Stage 1,2 and 3
- [VeloWire](http://www.velowire.com/article/880/en/the-race-route-of-the-first-tour-de-france-2016-stages-in-google-maps-google-earth.html) - first Tour de France 2016 stages in Google Maps/Google Earth
- [2travel2](http://www.2travel2.nl/tour-de-france-2016/tour-de-france-2016-etappes-tussen-start-en-finish-op-kaart-google-maps.html) - Tour de France 2016
- [CyclingStage](http://www.cyclingstage.com/tour-de-france-2016-route/) - Tour de France 2016 stages [1](http://www.cyclingstage.com/tour-de-france-2016-route/stage-1-tdf-2016/), [2](http://www.cyclingstage.com/tour-de-france-2016-route/stage-2-tdf-2016/), [13](http://www.cyclingstage.com/tour-de-france-2016-route/stage-13-tdf-2016/)

Some of these have Google Maps routes which is great, but that covers about 4 stages out of 21. Is there an online resource that has the routes for the other stages ?

Google Maps/Earth would be nice, but even a text based list of locations through which the Tour de Frances passes (rather than just start-end locations) for the stages would be useful.

Comment: Edited tags, changed question to be less temporally specific.

Comment: Did you have any luck finding this dataset? Anywhere it's available? The solution below doesn't work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official website](http://www.letour.com/le-tour/2016/us/overall-route.html) now has a list of all stages with links to (fairly small) maps, route profiles and estimated timings for various points on the route.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem provide what I'm after. As far as I can tell, I can see the start/end locations but no in between location that would allow me to get the exact path

Comment: If you go to "Route" on the yellow menu and pick a stage, for example [stage 8](http://www.letour.com/le-tour/2016/us/stage-8.html), you can see a reasonable map and, under "A sporting view" on the "Time Schedule" tab, a pretty detailed route outline (about 80 locations for that 184 km stage).

Comment: Correct (that [wasn't available](http://web.archive.org/web/20160505124806/http://www.letour.com/le-tour/2016/us/stage-9.html) around the time I checked, only some partial data). Thank you(+1)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to get detailed route maps for both TdF stages and other races run. I've spoken to both the UCI and the ASO and the indication is that newer events are pretty easy as there are archives of road books (given to teams, riders and other people involved in races) but very rapidly you'd need to find collectors of the paper road books.

ASO indicated they may have archival copies but they are not viewable by the public. This was several years ago though so perhaps they've changed.